# How to call a child action in the Home controller View called index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller named Product and a Partial View named Product details I want to call a 
child action inside the Index View of the default home controller and this is what I tried and the model is returned as null in the View.

Here is my Product Controller 
and here ids how I call the child action in my view.

```
@foreach (var product in Model)
{
  Html.Action("DisplayProduct", new { product.Id, product.Name, product.Description, product.Price } ) ;
}
```

and

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Product/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product { Id =1, Name ="Product 1", Description ="Description 1", Price = 10m},
            new Product { Id =2, Name ="Product 2", Description ="Description 2", Price = 20m},
            new Product { Id =3, Name ="Product 3", Description ="Description 3", Price = 30m},
            new Product { Id =4, Name ="Product 4", Description ="Description 4", Price = 40m}
        };
        return View(products);
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult DisplayProduct(Product product)
    {

        return PartialView("DisplayProduct", product);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an anonymous type with `new { product.Id, product.Name, product.Description, product.Price }` - just supply the product directly:

```
@foreach (var product in Model)
{
   @Html.Action("DisplayProduct", product)
}
```

and if your child action only returns the partial it is not needed at all as you can call the partial directly:

```
@foreach (var product in Model)
{
   @Html.Partial("DisplayProduct", product)
}
```